# Convert row or column in MS Word stored table into searchable array of text in MS Word document

Tags: arrays

SUMMARY:

I would like to extract strings of text from a row or a column of cells in an MS Word table, and then use each item in the array of text strings as a search term in an MS Word VBA macro.

DETAILS:

I have been given the task of creating a macro that will search and highlight certain forbidden words in legal documents (like "hereinafter," "thus, "expressly," etc.). Then a lawyer can quickly go through the document (either visually or by searching for highlighting) and deal with the forbidden words.

I have created a macro that invokes three subroutines that will search and highlight three list of words. Right now, I must type each search term individually into the subroutine as an array:

---

```
Sub Lawyerly_Terms_1()
'
' Lawyerly_Terms_1 Macro
' Highlilghts lawyerly terms for correction
' Single words, all forms
'
Dim range As range
Dim i As Long
Dim TargetList
```

'HERE IS WHERE I HAVE TO TYPE EACH INDIVIDUAL SEARCH TERM. I WOULD LIKE TO IMPORT THE TERMS HIGHLIGHTED IN GREEN FROM SEARCHTERMS.DOCM.

```
TargetList = Array("hereinafter", "thus", "expressly", "attach", "commence", "commencement", "covenant", "desire", "desirous", "endeavor", "express", "expressly", "following", "foregoing", "subsequent", "verbatim") ' put list of terms to find here. THESE CORRESPOND TO THE YELLOW HIGHLIGHTING IN  

For i = 0 To UBound(TargetList)

Set range = ActiveDocument.range

With range.Find
    .Text = TargetList(i)
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = True

Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

    Loop

    End With
    Next

End Sub
```

---

I have three such subroutines. (Beyond the fact that I have three subroutines, this may or may not be relevant to a persons understanding of my question. I include it in case it is relevant.)

*Subroutine Lawyerly_Terms_1: The first subroutine deals with single words, with the "Find all word forms" and "Find whole words only" options selected;

Subroutine Lawyerly_Terms_2: The second subroutine deals with multi-word phrases with non-alphabetic characters, so the "Find all word forms" and "Find whole words only" options are not available; and

Subroutine Lawyerly_Terms_3:  The third subroutine deals with searches that can best be done with wildcards, like "[Tt]here[a-z]{2,15}," which will find "Thereafter," "theretofore," and "thereby," but not "there" or "there's."*

However, I also have an MS Word document that has the search terms in the form of a table, called "C:\temp\SearchTerms.docm." It looks like this:

[MS Word document with table containing rows and columns of search terms.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15Ltf.png)

A copy is located here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/732h3je8qweashl/MS%20Word%20Table%20for%20Search%20Macros.docx?dl=0

I think what I need to do is declare the MS Word table (or just a row or column) to be a one-dimensional array, and then to put each array into my TargetList variable, and find an iterative process for searching for each item in the array. I have tried various things I have found on helpful websites (including this one), but without success.

I was for a time rather good at coding, even briefly being a double major in computer science and theater. But that was in 1975.

---

Comment: I should add that I have an idea about this approach: 

https://word.tips.net/T000502_Highlight_Words_from_a_Word_List.html

But I think that this would require using ReDim Preserve, and I don't know how to do that.